# How to test hadoop job performance

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I've implemented a frequent itemset map-reduce algorithm based on SON for Apache Hadoop. Now I need to test its performance, i.e. study how its execution time varies using different datasets and compare it with different versions of the algorithm in order to choose the best one.

So, I run several jobs on a 6-machines cluster and I have noticed that the execution time varies significantly even keeping the same dataset and the same algorithm version. I have come to the conclusion that in this type of environment the execution time is unpredictable because of the (un)availability of requested data in the machine where the computation runs.

How can I run this type of test in a reliable way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its common that at sometimes same Hadoop job takes varying over all time for the same dataset with same configurations. The main reason might be the availability of the execution containers to process the Map/Reduce tasks , which is uncertain.

The Elapsed of time of a job can be uncertain because the cluster where you run the job might be much busy with other jobs at sometimes when you run the job, your job might be getting very lesser containers for the execution.

If you are working on benchmarking job, dataset or configurations, then first make sure that the cluster very much free and the all the nodes are up and running.

One thing we can always notice to observe the job performance is from the job completion page consider the values of `Average Map Time`, `Average Reduce Time`,`Average Shuffle Time`, `Average Merge Time` , these metrics provide you reliable statistics across many job runs. The `Elapsed` time value might vary due to the resource availability.

[image]

Comment: @folli88, were you able to figure out the idea?.

Comment: Sadly, no. I've noticed that also these values are varying between the jobs. The possible solution can be something different from the execution time of the whole job, for me it’s only important to find the best algorithm based on the performances and I cannot find a way to do so.